# Unable to use subplot more than once without re-creating my grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
          X    Z  participantNum  obsScenario  startPos  targetPos
16000 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16001 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16002 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16003 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16004 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16005 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16006 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16007 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16008 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
16009 -16.0 -5.0         6950203            2         2          3
```

And I am using subplot to plot the X,Z data for each combination of grouping variables separately. Im using the following code to accomplish this:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(6,3)
grp = allDataF.groupby(['obsScenario', 'startPos', 'targetPos'])
for (group, allDataF), ax in zip(grp, axs.flat):
    ax.plot(allDataF.Z, allDataF.X, lw=0.3)
```

However, after I run this code for the first time, any subsequent time I run the code it only plots the data for the first subplot and leaves the rest empty.

Im pretty sure its because of the grp variable but Im not sure how to change the code so i can run it multiple times (e.g. changing plot settings and re-running to see how it looks without having to re-run everything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem might be because you use the same variable name `allDataF` for the bigger dataframe and the one inside `groupby`.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(6,3)
grp = allDataF.groupby(['obsScenario', 'startPos', 'targetPos'])

# change `allDataF` to `d`
for (group, d), ax in zip(grp, axs.flat):
    ax.plot(d.Z, d.X, lw=0.3)
```